# Can someone create a very complex transaction to try to fork the network?

Tags: transactions, script, blockchain-fork

If contracts are built into the code already, what is to stop someone from creating a transaction script that is very cpu intensive to verify, so that some computers accept the block with it and others do not?

Answer (score 0):

There are only a handful of types of scripts that are accepted.  The code must be modified to accept more types, which happens occasionally.  But you can't just write arbitrary scripts.

Also, I don't see how being CPU intensive would cause some computers to reject the block.